# EC2 instance connectivity issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance (Linux 2 AMI), in which I was able until recently to access outside ressources (Docker pull, curl google.com, ...). The instance was also reachable from the outside.

However, for some days now, the instance is still reachable, but cannot reach anything in the outside (docker pull, curl website, reach Azure, ...).

My configurations are the following:

- Network security: All traffics allowed in both inbound and outbound rules
- Network ACLs: Same (even though I have no clue what this is...)
- Route tables: I have a mapping 0.0.0.0/0 <=> igw-xxxxxxxx (status: active; propagated: no)

Between the working state and the not working states of my instance, I have done two things that may have had these consequences:

- Get an elastic ip in order to always have the same IP adress
- Route a domain name to this instance

My question: Do you have any ideas where the problem is coming from, and how I can fix it? I really don't know much in networks, so I don't know what is the best approach to fix the problem.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Check your security groups. Also I wonder if it's something to do with the instance configuration - create a new instance in the same security group and see if it works properly. You might find doing the training for AWS architect or sysop exams useful to learn some of the basic AWS concepts. AWS is a fairly complex enterprise environment, everyone starts somewhere :)

Comment: My security group allow all inbound and outbound traffic ... So the problem is not coming from here ... I agree for the training, but in the short term, I wish I could find a solution... What approach should I take ?

Comment: Try my suggestion in my comment above - new instance in same SG.